# Return all websites with specific keyword in base URL

Tags: google-search

How can I get all websites ****having **covid** keyword in their Base URL** and ending with specific country domain e.g eu**. So that i can get all websites like www.(.*covid.*).eu; examples below:-

- [www.xyzcovid.eu](http://www.xyzcovid.eu)
- [www.covidabc.eu](http://www.covidabc.eu)
- [www.xyzcovidabc.eu](http://www.xyzcovidabc.eu)

I have tried combining google search operators: inurl and site however it shows results from suburls as well like these [www.xyznews.com/abc-covid-trump-statement-xyz](http://www.xyznews.com/abc-covid-trump-statement-xyz)

Comment: Can you give one or two real examples of sites?

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing a research of available domains, instead of using Google ( websearch) use an specialized tool like the Domain Availability Search tools offered by domain registrars like Google Domains, GoDaddy, among others. Besides of telling you if the domain is available, some of them offer a list of similar domains so yo could have an idea of how unique is the domain that you are searching

By the other hand if you are looking existing domains, as is mentioned in [another answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/148388/88163), then you have get a list or registered domains. Some places publish interesting lists like Wikipedia:

- [List of the oldest currently registered Internet domain names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_oldest_currently_registered_Internet_domain_names=)

Looking at this lists could give you hints about other lists that might give you what you are looking for.

The above because Google (websearch) is good for indexing content but no so good for searching domains  / urls as it hasn't search operators like start with and doesn't support something like regular expressions.

Google (websearch) might help you find if someone already did a similar project and maybe also to learn about the knowledge/skills required to do it but not be the source to dump all the URLs in first place because Google doesn't index all the existing domains/websites.

Comment: My project require analytics-cum-analysis over the covid related websites that emanated in a particular country within particular time-frame. I thought i can dump all the URLs using google-search etc but it seems like a relatively complex and money spending task

Comment: @shaneaugmentin Google (websearch) might help you find if someone already did a similar project and maybe also to learn about the knowledge/skills required to do it but not be the source to dump all the URLs in first place because Google doesn't index all the existing domains/websites.

Comment: You write "it hasn't search operators like start with "  Yet he isn't looking for "start with". 
 He is looking for a keyword in a URL. And  Google does have the inurl keyword.  The problem is that doesn't specify base URL

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: you should not be able to.

To get a list of all host names that are available, you would need to do a zone-transfer. Only miss-configured DNS servers will allow you to do such a zone transfer.

There are a number of companies that will sell you a dump of the "whois" database against extortionate prices. These databases contain the information that you need, but you may not be willing to spend $500 for just the Netherlands.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for already built websites, basically i need to get list of all covid related websites built in this year especially within a particular country.

Comment: Read the question.  Your understood it as pretty much the opposite of what he asked for